# HTML PHP File Upload :: Uploaded File Doesn't Appear On Server

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I'm following [this tutorial](https://uploadcare.com/blog/how-to-make-html5-file-uploader/), trying to set up a simple website where a user can upload a file.  I should say that I'm really new to HTML and PHP.

So my webserver is Apache2, running on Ubuntu 16.04.  In my server's `/var/www/html/` directory, I have:

```
me@myServer:/var/www/html$ ls -l
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 ph9821 ph9821 1032 Feb 18 12:23 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ph9821 ph9821  480 Feb 18 12:18 uploader.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 ph9821 ph9821 4096 Feb 18 12:16 uploads
me@myServer:/var/www/html$
```

My test website is terribly boring:

[image: Boring Website]

The `index.html` describes my two buttons, one to upload a file from the client's machine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>DIY HTML5 File Uploader</h2>
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" id="file_to_upload">
    <hr>
    <input type="button" value="Upload To Server" id="upload_file_button">

    <script>
        document.getElementById('file_to_upload').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            window.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        });

        document.getElementById('upload_file_button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            uploadFile(window.selectedFile);
        });

        function uploadFile(file) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file_to_upload', file);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open('POST', 'uploader.php');
            ajax.send(formData);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The HTML references `uploader.php`, which is:

```
<?php

$file_name = $_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"];
$file_temp_location = $_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"];

if (!$file_temp_location) {
    echo "ERROR: No file has been selected";
    exit();
}

if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp_location, "/var/www/html/uploads/$file_name")){
    echo "$file_name upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "A server was unable to move the file";
}

?>
```

The PHP code should save the uploaded file in my `uploads` directory, indicated above.  Sadly, when you click "Choose File", select a file on your client machine, and then click "Upload to Server", the file does not appear in that directory.  In fact, it doesn't appear anywhere.  After uploading, I can't spot my target filename when using the Unix `find` command.  The uploaded file simply isn't saved on the server.

I'm missing something.  I can read through the above code and generally understand what each line is doing.  But I just don't have the experience to spot where I'm going wrong.  Can anyone offer any advice?  Thank you.

Comment: Web servers tend to delete temp files immediately after the web request disconnects. What is the output of the script?

Comment: @TravBroad Thanks Trav!  Uh... I don't know how to check the output of the script.  I saw those 'echo' statements, and I assume they're going to STDOUT, but how to check that from the command line?  I'm not sure

Comment: use postman to mock API calls, in this case send a POST request to `uploader.php`, I tested this for a bit. Mine worked fine just now

Comment: @xrayian That's a great suggestion, but I don't know how to use postman.  I'll see if I can't tease out the documentation.  You got my code to work on your machine?  That's interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the HTML for your index page. You do not need to use JS to handle file uploads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
          <h2>DIY HTML5 File Uploader</h2>
          <form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
                <hr>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this should be the PHP code for uploader.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$filename = basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $filename)) {
  echo "The file ". $filename . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

This code saves your uploaded file in the uploads folder.
If you have any answers or need me to explain the code, please ask.

Comment: Lars!  Thank you!  Apologies for the late response, we have a holiday weekend here in the USA.  So I implemented your code, and the move_uploaded_file() function is failing.  When I check the variables used in the PHP script, everything looks okay... so I assume this is a directory permission thing?  Uploaded files are to be stored in directory $target_dir.  My apache2 service is running as user root and www-data.  Should $target_dir be owned by one of those users?  Thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, I did a "chown www-data uploads" and now the file uploads to the server.  Awesome!!!  Thanks, man, you saved my project.  KUDOS!!!

Answer (score 1):

try changing your `move_uploaded_file()` dir and provide a path relative to the php file

```php
if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp_location, "uploads/$file_name")){
    echo "$file_name upload is complete";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, had no effect on my machine.  There must be something different between our two servers.  I wish I knew what...

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.4.3, which is the latest I can get from "apt-get install"

Comment: you can skip the ajax part and try using pure html method to post the file and verify what the php file says.

Comment: thanks, I will def try!

Comment: Doesn't work for me